# Can one monitor be set in same way just like you have two monitors?

Tags: desktop

Can one monitor be set in same way just like you have two monitors, so you can watch fullscreen youtube/videos and one program at each half?
Or this can be only done with two monitors?
I notice that program dont looks the same at one half of 32" compare to full screen at 20", some icons missing..

[image]

Comment: which program is that ?

Comment: That's a tall request.  The easiest solution to make both available to you would be workspaces, i.e. desktop switching.  https://www.pcworld.com/article/1936035/virtual-desktops-more-space-and-order-with-windows-10-and-11.html

Comment: @J.Cravens so  we cant make that one big monitor  operate
exactly the same   like I have  two  monitors?

Comment: @user707264 I posted an answer.  It's the best idea I've got.

Answer (score 1):

Windows has workspace's since version 10.
You can learn about using them and the settings from [here](https://www.pcworld.com/article/1936035/virtual-desktops-more-space-and-order-with-windows-10-and-11.html).

If you want to view and work with two different workspace's simultaneously on a single monitor, you might try virtual desktops combined with the "Snap" feature in Windows.

- **Open Task View:**
  — Press Windows key + Tab to open Task View.
- **Create Virtual Desktops:**
  — Create two virtual desktops by clicking on "New desktop". Bottom right corner in Task View.
- **Arrange Virtual Desktops:**
  — In Task View, you'll see both virtual desktops.
  — Drag and drop windows into each virtual desktop to organize them.
- **Use Snap Feature:**
  — Open the applications you want to view simultaneously.
  — Drag one application to one side of the screen until you see a transparent outline, then release it.
  — This will snap the application to one side of the screen.
  — Repeat the process for the second application on the other side of the screen.

You *should* have both virtual desktops visible simultaneously on your single physical monitor. Each side of the screen will show the contents of a different virtual desktop. I don't have Windows installed so this is going by memory and the above website.

Comment: I cant get two desktop at one screen...

Comment: @user707264 I kinda figured it was a hail mary.  It's not an easy to accomplish task.